# Some of my site's pages are retrieving the .css files from a different directory

Tags: 7, theming

I've been working on theming a Pages page on my local machine. This has been going fine, but now I have pushed the changes to a remote server and see that the site is trying to retrieve the .css file from the wrong directory.

On my local machine, this is fine. On the remote machine, it seems drupal is trying to retrieve the .css file from sites all:

```
@import url("http:/mysite.com/sites/all/themes/custom/mytheme/css/main.css");
```

Where as my local version has:

```
@import url("http://localdev.mysite.com/sites/mysite.com/themes/custom/mytheme/css/main.css");
```

Would anyone know why this is and how I could correct it?

Answer (score 0):

May I know where you have added CSS? on theme.info file or template.php

This issue occurring because of your theme has contained an absolute path, You need to replace absolute path the relative path.

First, you need to check that, On which file this CSS has called.

Remove from there and add CSS on theme.info file or template.php file.

On theme.info you need to add like `stylesheets[all][] = custom/mytheme/css/main.css`

On template.php you need to add css using `drupal_add_css` on `template_preprocess_html(&$variables)`.

Comment: Yeah, it really depends on how you have added the CSS files.

Comment: The .css is added to the theme's .info file, exactly like you have there: `stylesheets[all][] = css/main.css`. The path is accurate relative to the .info file.

Comment: Are you working on multisite?  Did you clear cache? 
Because On local your path  /sites/ where on remote server path is /mysite.com/.

If something is wrong with .info file then you can replace CSS from .info file to template.php file